# How i can dynamically build part of a string array inside Compose

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have this JSON array which I am passing as part of an http request body:

[image]

Here is the string:

```
"peoplePickerInput":"[ { \"Key\":\"@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo1']}\"},{ \"Key\":\"@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo2']}\" } ]"
```

Now I want to build a compose to check if the following is empty:

```
@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo2']}
```

And if so to only have one item inside the array, as follow:

```
"peoplePickerInput":"[ { \"Key\":\"@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo1']}\"}]"
```

So how I can do this inside compose and pass the output of the compose to the "Send HTTP request" action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add compose action before "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action and use expression in below format:

   ```
   if(empty(items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo2']), concat('[{ \"Key\":\"',items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo1'],'\"}]'), concat('[{ \"Key\":\"',items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo1'],'\"},{ \"Key\":\"',items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo2'],'\" }]'))
   ```
2. Then use output of compose action as value for `peoplePickerInput` property in "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action

Comment: worked for me....